# How to convert a float literal to an unsigned int of the same bit pattern

Tags: c++, c, types, casting, literals

In a header outside of my control, there is this:

```
typedef union {
    char * v_charp;
    int v_int;
    float v_float;
} value_t;

typedef struct var {
    char *name;
    value_t value;
} variable;

#define VARIABLE_DEF(Name, Value) {Name, {(char*)Value}}
```

They expect that in my code I'll do something like this:

```
variable my_variables[2] = {
    VARIABLE_DEF("Variable 1", 1),
    VARIABLE_DEF("Variable 2", 2)
};
```

Whoever wrote this apparently didn't consider that you might want to initialise the union with a floating-point literal.  So I need to figure out how to convert a literal float to an integer of the same bit-pattern.  If I could use an intermediate variable then it'd be easy:

```
float tmp;

variable my_variables[2] = {
    VARIABLE_DEF("Variable 1", tmp = 1.1f, *((unsigned int *)(&tmp))),
    VARIABLE_DEF("Variable 2", tmp = 2.2f, *((unsigned int *)(&tmp)))
};
```

But you can't use variables in struct initialisers.  What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
variable my_variables[2] = {
    VARIABLE_DEF("Variable 1", ((value_t){.v_float = 1.1f}.v_int)),
    VARIABLE_DEF("Variable 2", ((value_t){.v_float = 2.2f}.v_int)),
};
```

(Untested)

On second thought, how about defining a more flexible alternative to `VARIABLE_DEF` and using that when needed?

Something like

```
#define VARIABLE_DEF_ALT(Name, Value) {Name, {Value}}
#define VARIABLE_DEF_ALT2(Name, Field, Value) {Name, {.Field = Value}}

variable my_variables[2] = {
    VARIABLE_DEF_ALT("Variable 1", .v_float = 1.1f),
    VARIABLE_DEF_ALT2("Variable 2", v_float, 2.2f),
};
```

should work.

Or just skip the macro:

```
variable my_variables[2] = {
    {"Variable 1", {.v_float = 1.1f}},
    {"Variable 2", {.v_float = 2.2f}},
};
```

— is that actually the macro, or are you simplifying a much more complicated case for this discussion?

Comment: I saw the first part of this and thought, 'Brilliant, of course that's it!'  The compiler has other ideas, though.  The actual case is more complicated - there is still a single enum, struct and macro definition as shown, but there are many more members of each.  The macro really is adding value.

Comment: The compiler's problem is that designated initialisers of unions is an extension introduced in C99 and is not supported in C++ code by GCC.  It seems I incorrectly tagged this question C when it should have been C++ - I didn't realise it made this sort of difference.

Comment: The first snippet in this answer would invoke undefined behavior. I wouldn't advise using it.

Comment: @jpalecek - it would involve undefined behaviour, but certainly no worse than the macro writer already causes by treating everything passed to him as a `char *` for the purpose of initialising the union.

Comment: With a minor tweak the first snippet here works.  The tweak is that G++ doesn't support the C99-style designated initialisers, but **does** support the GNU-extension-style initialisers.  So `((value_t){v_f: 1.1f}.v_int)` is a valid input to the macro.  I've updated the answer to reflect this.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tom, yeah, C99 & C11 have diverged somewhat from C++.  It’s still possible to stick to the intersection, but the C++-incompatible features can be _really_ handy—like here, for example.  BTW, where is that G++ extension documented?  More importantly, is it still there in recent GCC releases?

Comment: I found the feature [here in the GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html), but I note it has been labeled “obsolete since GCC 2.5”. Hopefully they won’t remove it until the C++ committee adds designated initializers to the language—or GCC adds it as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a function like `static int f(float x) { return *(int*)&x; }` would do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a function like that from Michael Kerlin's answer in the code, because function call cannot be used in initializers.

But you can write a program that does such a conversion and then copy/paste the resulting integer value into your program! (with a nice comment saying what value it really is).

Comment: Attractive, since the code is actually generated from another source anyway.  However, the generation is done by XSLT, and the thought of mangling bit patterns in XSLT is enough to give me nightmares...

Answer (score 0):

Used named initializers:

```
variable my_variables[2] = {
    VARIABLE_DEF("Variable 1", 1),
    { .name = "Variable 2", .value.v_float = 1.1f }
};
```